# mxn relation in Data Models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamodel

i have the following Problem:

I have three different data models : customer , periods and request. A request consist of the customer_id and the periods_id (i dont know why its periodS_id because i genereated a scaffold called period). Now if i want to create a request i want to choose a customer and a period so my code in the form.html.erb of requests is:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Kunde auswählen' %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Zeitfenster auswählen' %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :periods_id, Period.all , :id, :description %>
</div>
```

and this works pretty well. I can choose the name of the customers and peridos but then if i want to create a request i get the error message undefinded method, because he cant display the name of periods in the show.html.erb:

```
  <%= @request.customer.name%>


  <%= @request.periods.name%>
```

My idea is a mistake in the datamodels. I´m not sure if this mxn relationship works. Here the datamodels:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :periods_id, :customer_id, presence: true

belongs_to :customer
belongs_to :period
end

class Period < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :requests, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :customers, :through => :requests
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :requests, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :periods, :through => :requests
end
```

and it works for customer: if i delete period.name he can show the name of the specific customer.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Its give error of `period` because `request` model belongs to `period`, not `request has_many period`

```
<%= @request.period.name%>
```

Change `.periods` to `.period`

Comment: i changed to period.name but are you sure that a request can have many period or i undestood wrong ? what excactly i need to change in the datamodels?

Comment: if i do 'request has_many period'  every period is shown as 'Period'